# Using the external IP service of the load balancer for different pod Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have deployed RabbitMQ in Kubernetes using a service with the load balancer type. When creating a service, an external IP is created. Could you please tell me if I can bind another deployment to this IP with other ports? Thanks.

Comment: When you say its creates external IP, is it creating an external load balancer outside Kubernetes and attaching to the k8s cluster ? If that is the case, Yes.

Comment: Do you still work on this? I didn't see any response to the reply.

Comment: yes it creates an Azure Load Balancer, but I don't know how to use it in other services

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you just have to create a service with multiple ports, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-name
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  - name: any other port
    port: <port-number>
    targetPort: <target-port>
  selector:
    app: app
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And you will output similar to this:

```
$kubectl get svc
service-name   LoadBalancer   <Internal-IP>   <External-IP>        80:30870/TCP,443:32602/TCP,<other-port>:32388/TCP
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have two different applications and i have to use different selectors